# how to run gulp tasks in order?

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-task

I am trying to concat all the css files into one released css file by running task:

```
gulp.task('task one', () => {  
    gulp.src([Dir + "**/*.css"])
        .pipe(concat(outFilename + ".css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir));
});
```

After that, because the font path in the output css file is not correct, so I need to modify the path.

```
gulp.task('task two', () => {
    var urlAdjuster = require('gulp-css-url-adjuster');

    //change font path for released css files
    gulp.src([releasePath + "/*.css"])
        .pipe(urlAdjuster({
            replace: ['../../fonts', '../fonts'],
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(releasePath + "/"));
);
```

In order to make it happen, I need to run these two tasks separately one by one. 
How can I run these two tasks in order and put them into one task.

I have tried: 
`series = require('gulp-series');` ----not working

```
gulp.task('task two', ['task one'], function () {
    // Gulp. src (...
});
```

-----not working

---update--------------------------------------------------------
I used return but it is now working. The actual codes are:

```
function procHTMLForRelease(stream, file) {
    gulp.src([Dir + "**/*.css"])
        .pipe(concat(outFilename + ".css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir));

}

function processRelease() {


    // Grab all html files in the folder.
    // Loop over them, process them, then spit em out.
    gulp.src([paths.Source + "/*.html"])
        .pipe(foreach(procHTMLForRelease))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.Release));

    // Process image files
    gulp.src([paths.Source + "images/*.*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.Release + "images/"));

    // Copy font files
    gulp.src([paths.html + "fonts/*.*", paths.html + "fonts/*/*.*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.release + "/fonts/"));


}  



gulp.task('task one', () => { return processRelease();
});
```

Comment: Your original codes are totally different from the updated ones, How come?

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('task two', ['task one'], function () {
    // gulp.src( ...
});
```

This is correct, it sets `task one` as a dependancy for `task two`. However, for this to work, `task one` needs to `return`.

```
gulp.task('task one', () => {  
    return gulp.src([Dir + "**/*.css"])
        .pipe(concat(outFilename + ".css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir));
});
```

Comment: @ lofihelsinki I have used "return", but its not really working, see my updates

Comment: You have to put each `gulp.src` into it's own task and return the `gulp.src`, as in my answer. Your original example should work if you just add `return` in front of `gulp.src`. Your update example doesn't have anything as a dependacy, so it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your updated code like this to make it `return`.

```
gulp.task('taks one', function () {

    // Grab all html files in the folder.
    // Loop over them, process them, then spit em out.
    var one = gulp.src([paths.Source + "/*.html"])
        .pipe(foreach(procHTMLForRelease))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.Release));

    // Process image files
    var two = gulp.src([paths.Source + "images/*.*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.Release + "images/"));

    // Copy font files
    var three = gulp.src([paths.html + "fonts/*.*", paths.html + "fonts/*/*.*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.release + "/fonts/"));

   // Return
   return [ one, two, three];

});
```

The tasks inside the function will run asynchronously, but you can make another function to depend on those all being done.

```
gulp.task('task two', ['task one'], function () {
    // Gulp. src (...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone has the same problem and looking for a solution: 
Here is what I do to fix it: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence

For example:

```
// This will run in this order:
// * build-clean
// * build-scripts and build-styles in parallel
// * build-html
// * Finally call the callback function
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence('build-clean',
              ['build-scripts', 'build-styles'],
              'build-html',
              callback);
});
```